# Android - Deleting Key Element from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

I'm using the following method to delete a key element on the **SharedPreferences** of my app. I'm calling it from within a fragment. The problem is that the element is never deleted from SharedPreferences and I get no LogCat output. Is there something wrong with this method? Context perhaps? The **deleteFromSharedPreferences** is located in a class called **Utils** and the triggering method is located on a fragment called **PagerFragment**. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
        private void deleteCity() {
            deleteFromSharedPref(mCityId, getContext());
        }
}

public class Utils {
        public static void deleteFromSharedPref(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove(key);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the deleteCity() method?

Comment: Did you try editor.commit()?